# SCSS Intellisense repeats variable symbol after auto completion

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, intellisense

I have installed the SCSS Intellisense VS Code extension and [it seems that all is well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nPG7.png) except that the auto-completion feature [repeats the variable symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9WN9.png) when you auto-complete variables, which is super annoying.

Has anyone else encountered this problem with SCSS Intellisense? How can I fix this!

For context, I am using scss in a Vue `<style>` code block and I am importing a `variables.scss` script from a separate folder.